# Casper JS not posting data to local host

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am working with casper JS and trying to scrap a website information. I have written the code and that works perfectly, in a sense that I am able to grab all of the required information from that website. Actually, its career  pager of a company and I am scrapping the job listings from them. And the problem occurs, when I sent the data to mysql database through `casper.thenOpen(url,{method:"POST",data:somedata},function(){ })`. That works perfect as well. For example with this method I am able to insert static data like this :

```js
$jobs_ins = "INSERT INTO company_jobs VALUES (NULL,'inc','job_title','job_link','job_loc','job_date','refNo','jType','jField','jLevel','jTime',10)";

if ($con - > query($jobs_ins)) {
  echo "Inserted Row";
} else {
  echo "Not Inserted";
}
`
```

But, when i send the grab data, none of the data get inserted. I don't know what is the problem, but when i `console.log()` the data every data displays perfect.

Below is my casper JS scripts :

```js
var casper = require("casper").create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "error",
  clientScripts: ['plugins/jquery.js']
});
var X = require("casper").selectXPath,
  P = 1,
  MAINURL = "https://www.tempozeitarbeit.de/tempozeitarbeit/fuer-arbeitnehmer/stellenangebote-ulm-heidenheim/?page=" + P,
  PAGES,
  B = [],
  D = [],
  DETAILSURL = "https://www.tempozeitarbeit.de/contenido/includes/jobportal/jobs.php?id=";


casper.start(MAINURL);
casper.then(function() {
  PAGES = casper.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementsByClassName("jobpager")[0].children.length;
  })

  //Send information of the Company Start
  var company_name = "TEMPOZEITARBEIT";
  var company_loc = "GERMANY";
  var company_logo = "https://www.tempozeitarbeit.de/cms/images/tempo_logo.png";
  var company_link = "https://www.tempozeitarbeit.de/cms/";
  casper.thenOpen("http://localhost/fiverr/Crawl%20The%20Jobs%20-%20Guisipe/modal_scripts.php", {
    method: "POST",
    data: "add_companies=true&company_name=" + company_name + "&company_loc=" + company_loc + "&company_logo=" + company_logo + "&company_link=" + company_link + "&ref_id=6",
  })
  //Send information of the Company End

  nextPage(MAINURL);
})


function nextPage(_URL_) {
  if (P == PAGES) {
    console.log("S C R A P P I N G F I N I S H E D !");
    return;
  } else {
    //BRIEF START-----------------------------------
    casper.thenOpen(_URL_);
    casper.then(function() {
      console.log("\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
      console.log("S C R A P P I N G P A G E # " + P);
      B = this.evaluate(function() {
        var d = [];
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName("row job-table");
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          d.push({
            id: el[i].getAttribute("id"),
            title: el[i].children[0].textContent,
            loc: el[i].children[1].textContent,
            type: el[i].children[2].textContent
          })
        }
        return d;
      })
      for (var i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        casper.thenOpen("http://localhost/fiverr/Crawl%20The%20Jobs%20-%20Guisipe/modal_scripts.php", {
          method: "POST",
          data: "add_jobs=true&job_title=" + B[i].title + "&refNo=_" + (i + 1) + "&job_date=none&updated_time=none&jType=" + B[i].type + "&jField=none&job_loc=" + B[i].loc + "&job_link=&jLevel=none&jTime=none",
        })
        getDetails(DETAILSURL + B[i].id, i)
      }
      P++;
      nextPage("https://www.tempozeitarbeit.de/tempozeitarbeit/fuer-arbeitnehmer/stellenangebote-ulm-heidenheim/?page=" + P);
    })
    //BRIEF END -------------------------
  }
}

//DETAILS START --------------------------------------
function getDetails(_DETAILSURL_, _I) {
  casper.thenOpen(_DETAILSURL_);
  casper.then(function() {
    console.log("S C R A P P I N G J O B O F F E R # " + (_I + 1));
    D = this.evaluate(function() {
      var or = "https://www.tempozeitarbeit.de/cms/";
      var els = document.body.children[1].children;
      var dd = [],
        final = [];
      var apply = els[0].children[0].getAttribute("href");
      for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {

        if (els[i].nodeName == "H3" && els[i + 1].nodeName == "UL") {
          var temp = [];
          for (var j = 0; j < els[i + 1].children.length; j++) {
            temp.push(els[i + 1].children[j].textContent)
          }
          dd.push({
            head: els[i].textContent,
            desc: temp
          });
        } else if (els[i].nodeName == "H3" && els[i + 1].nodeName == "DIV") {
          dd.push({
            head: els[i].textContent,
            desc: els[i + 1].textContent
          });
        }
      }
      final.push({
        link: or + apply,
        data: dd
      });
      return final;
    })

    // console.log("Link - "+D[0].link);
    // for (var i = 0; i < D[0].data.length; i++) {
    //    console.log("Head - "+ D[0].data[i].head)
    //    console.log("Description - "+ D[0].data[i].desc)
    // }

  })
  return D;
}
//DETAILS   END --------------------------------------












casper.run();
```

And this is the PHP script I receive the data trough :

```js
if (isset($_POST["add_jobs"])) {

  $job_title = $_POST["job_title"];
  $job_link = $_POST["job_link"];
  $job_loc = $_POST["job_loc"];
  $job_date = $_POST["job_date"];
  $refNo = $_POST["refNo"];
  $jType = $_POST["jType"];
  $jField = $_POST["jField"];
  $jLevel = $_POST["jLevel"];
  $jTime = $_POST["jTime"];

  $inc = $_COOKIE["id"];

  $jobs_ins = "INSERT INTO `company_jobs` VALUES (NULL,'$inc','$job_title','$job_link','$job_loc','$job_date','$refNo','$jType','$jField','$jLevel','$jTime',10)";

  if ($con - > query($jobs_ins)) {
    echo "Inserted Row";
  } else {
    echo "Not Inserted";
  }

}
```

Comment: Okay, let's think. If you can `console.log` your data and see it's correct, then — what do you think points of failure might be?

Comment: Thats what I don't know @Vaviloff. But on the console its displaying perfectly , but the database doesnt get populated !

Comment: (Well we already knew it looks good on console) Tell me: what are possible reasons for the database not to be populated?

Comment: the text I grabbed have some escape sequences, like tabs, etc, I used trim() method but still failed. Before this I have scrapped many sites that worked fine for me , but after that I updated my wamp server to 3.* ad before it was 2.* and PHP versions. So, may be because of that ?

Comment: Okay, good, and how can we check for database errors if there are any? And can we check somehow if data is received by PHP at all? And if yes can we look at the data?

Comment: The problem is , `casper.thenOpen()` method doesnt receive any response